How to get my Azure Function to connect to my SQL database
I'm currently trying and failing to connect get an Azure Function to work. I created a SQL Server with a database.
I also created an Azure Function, I configured cors to allow all origins, I have set up that the connection string of the database in my Azure function, I have all the environment variables like DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, etc. all set up.
I added all of the out IP's of the Function app in my SQL Server, I also enabled it so that all Azure resources can use it, I even added my Azure function as a Microsoft Entra admin.
I installed SQL Server using the kudu console.
Nothing works - I always seem to get a 500 error with no log.
This is the code for my HttpTrigger, I need to only use the Azure portal editor, I cannot create another project in VS Code to publish, what can I do?
const sql = require('mssql');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {
        // Log that the function has started
        context.log('Function execution started.');
        
        // Set up connection to Azure SQL Database
        const config = {
            user: process.env.DB_USER, 
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
            server: process.env.DB_SERVER, 
            database: process.env.DB_DATABASE, 
            options: {
                encrypt: true,
                enableArithAbort: true
            }
        };

        // Connect to SQL Server
        await sql.connect(config);
        context.log('Successfully connected to SQL Server.');

        // Send a success message
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: "Successfully connected to the database!" // Success message
        };
    } catch (err) {
        // Log the error for debugging
        context.log.error('Error occurred:', err);

        // Return a 500 error with a message
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: `Error connecting to the database: ${err.message}` // Error message
        };
    } finally {
        context.log('Function execution completed.');
    }
};

This is the error I get

Executing 'Functions.GetGptwai' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=)
Sending invocation id: '
Posting invocation id: on workerId:
[Error]   Executed 'Functions.GetGptwai' (Failed, Id=, Duration=1ms)

I tried to allow all origins in cors, setting my Azure function as admin, adding all ips to the whitelist

Did you check the logstream?

If you run your script locally, does it work? As this is quite plain python I doubt it has anything to do with the function host. You can start and debug that function locally via the function tools/vs code.

Check if below solution helps @N4CHOL.

Follow below steps to connect Azure function app to Azure SQL database, refer MSDOC for code.

Create a SQL server and database.
Deploy the function code to Azure functionapp.

My function code:

const { app, input } = require('@azure/functions');

const sqlInput = input.sql({
    commandText: 'select [Id], [order], [title], [url], [completed] from dbo.ToDo',
    commandType: 'Text',
    connectionStringSetting: 'SqlConnectionString',
});

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    extraInputs: [sqlInput],
    handler: (request, context) => {
        context.log('HTTP trigger and SQL input binding function processed a request.');
        const toDoItems = context.extraInputs.get(sqlInput);
        return {
            jsonBody: toDoItems,
        };
    },
});

Add SQL server connection string in Function App=>Environment Variables=>App Settings:
"SqlConnectionString":"Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=rkdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={Username};Password={Password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"


Navigate to SQL server=>Access Control(IAM)=>Assign Sql Server contributor role to your UserID or service principal.

Run the deployed function:
Function App Logs:
2024-12-06T10:56:28Z   [Verbose]   AuthenticationScheme: WebJobsAuthLevel was successfully authenticated.
2024-12-06T10:56:28Z   [Verbose]   AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2024-12-06T10:56:28Z   [Verbose]   Authorization was successful.
2024-12-06T10:56:28Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=aa8cf697-fd96-499c-90a9-0c7cb310b76d)
2024-12-06T10:56:28Z   [Verbose]   Sending event Create
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Verbose]   Sending event Convert
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Information]   1 row(s) queried from database: rkdb using Command: select [Id], [order], [title], [url], [completed] from dbo.ToDo
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: 'aa8cf697-XX499c-90a9-0c7cb310b76d
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:aa8cf697-fd9XX9-0c7cb310b76d on workerId:4b6649e1-XX-b666-0abca6973c96
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Information]   HTTP trigger and SQL input binding function processed a request.
2024-12-06T10:56:30Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=aa8cf697-fd96-XXb310b76d, Duration=1628ms)

Response:

